# Using a class for reading config from files

Tags: python, object-oriented, classes

The goal of my current piece of work is to read from a global config file all the settings and then from the local file only those settings that a user has chosen.

Firstly I wrote a function but then I needed a class. It's my first working class in Python, and I ask if you can kindly note its defects. Although it works, I think it can for sure be written more correctly and concisely.

Here's all the beginning:

```
# files to be read from
cmd_parameter = "config_1.cfg"
cmd_parameter_global = "global.cfg"

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    cmd_parameter = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("Error: there should be one argument after program name - config file name")
    exit(-1)

config_file = []
config_file_global = []

# reading user's config file
try:
    with open(cmd_parameter, 'r') as config_file_name:
        config_file = config_file_name.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File '", sys.argv[1], "' not exists or not available")
    exit(-1)

# reading global config file
try:
    with open(cmd_parameter_global, 'r') as config_file_global_name:
        config_file_global = config_file_global_name.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Global configuration file '", cmd_parameter_global, "' not exists or not available")
    exit(-1)

# parsing config file, reading values from it to list and matching parameters with a given argument
# parameters in config file should start with <conf_key_split1>, value should be separated from parameter by <conf_key_split2>
config_param_user = []
config_value_user = []
config_param_global = []
config_value_global = []
config = ""
conf_key_split1 = '.'
conf_key_split2 = '='
conf_key_split3 = ','

# reading user's config file
for line in config_file:
    if line.startswith(conf_key_split1):
        line = line.rstrip().split(conf_key_split1)
        line = line[1]

        line = line.rstrip().split(conf_key_split2)
        config_param_user.append(line[0])
        config_value_user.append(line[1])

# reading global config file
for line in config_file_global:
    if line.startswith(conf_key_split1):
        line = line.rstrip().split(conf_key_split1)
        line = line[1]

        line = line.rstrip().split(conf_key_split2)
        config_param_global.append(line[0])
        config_value_global.append(line[1])
```

And here is the class itself:

```
# class for reading config from user's and global config file the list of params names list and the list of values
class configFromFile():
    def config_from_file_userfile(self, param):
        index = config_param_user.index(param)
        if config_value_user[index]:
            config_value = config_value_user[index]
        else:
            print('The value of the parameter "', param, '" was not found in', cmd_parameter)
            exit(-1)

        return config_value

    def config_from_file_global(self, param):
        index = config_param_global.index(param)
        if config_value_global[index]:
            config_value = config_value_global[index]
        else:
            print('The value of the parameter "', param, '" was not found in', cmd_parameter_global)
            exit(-1)

        return config_value

    def main(self, param):
        if param in config_param_global:
            config = self.config_from_file_global(param)
        elif param in config_param_user:
            config = self.config_from_file_userfile(param)
        else:
            print('The parameter "', param, '" was not found in', cmd_parameter, 'and in', cmd_parameter_global)
            exit(-1)

        return config
```

Usage:

```
names = configFromFile().main('names')
```

Comment: You can also use ChainMap (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects ) objects to represent your configuration information with arbitrary number of chained configuration files. Documentation do have examples.

Comment: Please see http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/32391

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you state:

> I wrote a function but then I needed a class

Looking at the class you wrote, I would say you were incorrect there. The class has no `__init__`, holds no state, and only uses `self` to access other methods on the class. There is absolutely no reason for it to be a class.

---

Duplication is the programmer's arch enemy - every time you have the same thing written out more than once is an opportunity to reduce the amount of code you write, test and maintain. For example:

```
# reading user's config file
try:
    with open(cmd_parameter, 'r') as config_file_name:
        config_file = config_file_name.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File '", sys.argv[1], "' not exists or not available")
    exit(-1)

# reading global config file
try:
    with open(cmd_parameter_global, 'r') as config_file_global_name:
        config_file_global = config_file_global_name.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Global configuration file '", cmd_parameter_global, "' not exists or not available")
    exit(-1)
```

Note that these do more-or-less *exactly* the same thing, and should therefore be refactored to something like:

```
def extract_file(filename, message):
    try:
        with open(filename) as file_:
            return file_.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(message.format(filename))
        exit(-1)
```

and then called like:

```
config_file = extract_file(cmd_parameter,
                           "File '{}' not exists or not available")
```

You should apply this throughout your code - you have basically written the same program twice, with minor adjustments, for the two config files, which makes no sense.

---

The [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is a key data structure in Python, and would make all of your code *vastly* simpler. You could create a dictionary of the global configuration options, then `update` it with the local values. Lookups by name would then be `O(1)`, rather than `O(n)`, and you could get rid of all the `index`ing.

---

In terms of general structure, you have lots of code running at the top level of the script. This is generally a bad idea, and will give you problems if you later want to `import` this functionality elsewhere. You should define an entry point (usually, but not necessarily, called `main`) that takes the file locations as parameters and call it something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main('global.cfg', sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print("Error: there should be one argument after program name - config file name")
        exit(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. About code at the top level - I'm currently writing functions, and what you've written is very handy for me now. I'll probably leave the class because it is comfortable for me to have structure like that when I can just add more methods inside if there would be, say, more config files.

Comment: @nonrandom_passer but those methods are all duplicates. If you adopt the dictionary version, all you need is one function to parse a specified file to a config dictionary, then `dict.update` in the correct order. You could also use an existing file format, e.g. JSON, rather than define your own.

Comment: First of all, thanks again for your remarks. I used the `dict` and updated the main question, pls take a look. And I also would appreciate if you'll comment on 2 more things. First is an entry point that you've mentioned (sorry, I didn't quite got it - did you mean to put all the main body of a script into a `main` method?

Comment: And the second is that I've tried to put all imports inside `try`-`except` blocks that I have also in the beginning to one function but did not succeed. Can you please comment? `def import_module(module_name, custom_module_name, message):
    try:
        import module_name as custom_module_name
    except ImportError:
        print(message.format(module_name))

import_module("random", "rnd", "Importing module '{}' did not succeed")`

Comment: Putting the whole script inside a `main` is one way to do it, but it would be much better to split into lots of short functions, then have a `main` that just calls the appropriate functions at the appropriate times.

Comment: Why have you done the `import` like that?! Standard library modules will always be available (and your script won't work without them), `import random as rnd` is perfectly acceptable, and will throw an appropriate `ImportError` if something does go wrong. And you can't `import` from strings like that; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/301134/3001761

Comment: One last moment: how would you recommend to declare variables in a general case? Is is acceptable to make them global like I did or to use smth similar to getter (it's properties in Python, right?) and to make variables private?

Comment: There isn't a general case. Sometimes class and instance attributes are appropriate, sometimes you need explicit parameters and return values. In this case, as *you don't need the class*, you should use the latter.  `global` scope is rarely the right choice, except for constants.